# Flutter sqflite, retreiving data from a rawQuery

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have the following rawQuery

```
final maps = await db.rawQuery("""
select r.id, r.name, r.description,r.created_by,
a.id,a.name,a.description from Resources r 
left join Resource_Attribute ra on ra.resource_id = r.id
left join AttributeItems a on ra.attribute_id=a.id
""");
```

My question is how do I retrieve the data from all the columns in my query?  Doing the following

```
 maps.forEach((dbItem){
     String resourceId = dbItem["r.id"];
```

doesn't seem to work.  **dbItems** is a map but contains only the four columns in the **Resources** table.  dbItem["r.id"]  returns a null.

dbItems does contain a "row" field which is an array with all the field. Is there way to access that?

Comment: for testing: `maps.forEach(print)`, what do you see?

Comment: I only see the 4 columns which are part of the Resources table : id, name, description and created_by.

Comment: seems that `a.id,a.name,a.description` do not exist in your `AttributeItems` table for given join

Comment: They do,   The row field I referred to earlier contains them as well.

Comment: tried to use [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3) tool to be sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at `dbItem.keys`, you will see that it is `['id','name',...]` not `['r.id','r.name']`.

You can access your resource id using:

```dart
var resourceId = dbItem['id'] as String;
```

You can name a column explicitely using `AS`. For example:

```
var resultSet = await db.rawQuery("SELECT r.id AS r_id FROM test r");
// Get first result
var dbItem = resultSet.first;
// Access its id
var resourceId = dbItem['r_id'] as String;
```

Answer (score 0):

As alextk suggested , I changed my query to

```
    select r.id as resource_id, r.name as resource_name, r.description as resource_descr,r.created_by as resource_created_by,
a.id as attribute_id,a.name as attribute_name,a.description as attribute_descr from Resources r 
left join Resource_Attribute ra on ra.resource_id = r.id
left join AttributeItems a on ra.attribute_id=a.id
```

and that did the trick.